# What are the different terminal emulators available in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, xterm

When I type `echo $TERM` on my terminal it shows me `xterm`. From there itself I believe there are more than one terminal in Ubuntu. Is it the name of the terminal that I am using? I have seen some computer experts using terminal which is having lots of colored text and all. Actually how many types of terminals are there in Ubuntu?

Comment: The given link does not answer my question. I want to know the different types of terminals available in Ubuntu.

Comment: Then your question should be closed as too broad.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Provided "different types" is limited to the different values that `TERM` can take on, I don't think this is too broad. If we were to interpret this as asking what all the differences are between all different terminal emulators that can be run in Ubuntu, of course that *would* be too broad, but I think this is asking what the different values of `TERM` are and what they mean.

Comment: [This answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43951/63286) on the Unix site should apply.

Comment: @Rinzwind `The underlying software usage determines how it works.` Which is exactly why I wouldn't want to put 'noodle-soup' as my $TERM. I am highly sceptical that this is too broad. An answer doesn't have to list *every single possible* variable, just the most common ones and explain why they are important.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer [here](http://www.tecmint.com/linux-terminal-emulators/). May the way I asked the question was little confusing. I was actually looking for terminal emulators. But before I read this, I never knew that there are emulators exist for terminal.

There are a number of terminal emulators available for Linux and so for Ubuntu which give more usability based on your application. Usability in the sense, for example, there is a terminal emulator which shows the thumbnails when you list the files under a directory using `ls` command. There is another terminal emulator called `Terminator` in which you can split your window horizontally and vertically o that you can evaluate all you activities in the same screen without switching the tab.

The one I prefer for my application is `Terminator` as I have to perform more than one processes on my terminal, like I have to run a scan on a server and at the same time I want to edit a file using vim. I can see the scanning on my right side and at the same time I can edit the file also. Thumbs up!

Comment: look up online cool-retro-term and byobu. Byobu can create terminal tabs kind of like a web browser with bunch of indicators, like battery life and time(so saves time on writing elaborate scripts), and cool-retro-term, well, just has cool style. Oh, and Byobu works even in tty type of consoles ! just call it when you log in, and enjoy

Comment: It would be better if you could summarize the content of the linked post. Link-only  answers become useless if the link goes stale.

Comment: @muru I have added a slight explanation. Hope it adds. :)